# Soap Web Service Not Deployed in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, soap

I am creating and deploying a SOAP webservice in Tomcat 6 through eclipse.

Following is my code.

**Interface**

```
package com.hcl.anil;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface CalWebService
{
    int add(int a,int b);
}
```

**Implementing class**

```
package com.hcl.anil;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface="com.hcl.anil.CalWebService", portName="calWebServicePort",serviceName="calWebService")
public class CalWebServiceImpl implements CalWebService
{

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }

}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<listener>
        <listener-class>
                com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CalWebService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CalWebService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CalWebService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**sun-jaxws.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
  version="2.0">
  <endpoint
      name="CalWebService"
      implementation="com.hcl.anil.CalWebServiceImpl"
      url-pattern="/CalWebService"/>
</endpoints>
```

When I try to deploy the web service in tomcat6, I get the following error.

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/istack/localization/LocalizableMessageFactory$ResourceBundleSupplier
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.istack.localization.LocalizableMessageFactory$ResourceBundleSupplier
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 33 more
```

I have included the following Jars in my project lib folder and **jaxb-impl-2.2.3** jar actually has the class that says missing.But it does not have the **$ResourceBundleSupplier** part of the class.

Jars in the lib folder are follows.

**gmbal-api-only,ha-api,jaxb-api-2.2.3,jaxb-core,jaxb-impl,jaxb-impl-2.2.3,
jaxb-xjc-2.2.3,jaxws-api,jaxws-rt,management-api,policy,stax-ex,streambuffer**

I am stuck with this almost a day now and I thoroughly searched and tried many solutions.If someone can help, appreciate it very much.

For clearer note, actually I am following this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGlPXKJo_6U

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure is a hassle and i was stuck in a similar problem. You can use the following dependencies to solve the problem although you might need some trial and error work to actually make this work since there can be some other dependencies as well.

Include these in the pom file and try out. I worked with Tomcat 8.5.38 but would work with Tomcat 6  as well.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.ha</groupId>
        <artifactId>ha-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
        <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.gmbal</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmbal-api-only</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-b003</version>
    </dependency>
```